# react pagination using tanstack react query, buttons are not working

Tags: reactjs, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

I am using jsonplaceholder api and trying to fetch results on different pages, for that I am
using tanstack react query, however my buttons seem to not work? Can somebody please guide me in
the right direction?

I am having a page hook and on clicking button this hook is incrementing or decrementing page
number but still it is not fetching new results.

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import {
  QueryClient,
  QueryClientProvider,
  useQuery,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(

   <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <App />
    </QueryClientProvider>

);
```

```
export const fetchData = async ({queryKey}) => {
    const page = queryKey[1];
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_page=${page + 1}`
    );
    return res.json();
}
```

```
import { useQueryClient, useQuery, QueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Component1 } from './components/Component1';
import { fetchData } from './components/fetchData';


function App() {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const { isLoading, error, data, isFetching,
    isPreviousData, } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["repoData", page],
    queryFn: fetchData,
  });
  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isPreviousData && data?.hasMore) {
      queryClient.prefetchQuery({
        queryKey: ['repoData', page + 1],
        queryFn:()=>fetchData(page +1)
    })
  }
},[data, isPreviousData, page, queryClient])





  if (isLoading) return "Loading...";

  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((user) => (
        <div key={user.id}>
          <>{user.title}</>
          <p>{user.completed ? "True" : "False"}</p>
          <strong> {user.id}</strong>
        </div>
      ))}
      <span>Current Page: {page + 1}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => setPage((old) => Math.max(old - 1, 0))}
        // disabled={page === 0}
      >
        Previous Page
      </button>{" "}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          // if (!isPreviousData && data.hasMore) {
          //   setPage((old) => old + 1);
          // }
          setPage((old)=>(data?.hasMore? old +1 : old))
        }}
        // Disable the Next Page button until we know a next page is available
        // disabled={isPreviousData || !data?.hasMore}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
      {isFetching ? <span> Loading...</span> : null}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on further troubleshooting , in next button onClick ``` setPage((old)=>(data?.hasMore? old +1 : old))``` is not updating the state, so looks like a problem here, I m beginner and its not the reason to just get the answer from community, If I could be directed in the right direction , it will be much appreciated. however I will keep working on it. Thanks